# Let $f:A→B$ be a ring morphism and $φ : \operatorname{Spec}B→\operatorname{Spec}A$ its induced continuous map, then prove that $\rm im\ φ ⊆ V(\ker f)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, zariski-topology

Today I was asked this question by my teacher:

> Let $A$,$\ B$ be two conmutative rings with unity lef $f :A \rightarrow B$ be a ring morphism and $φ : \operatorname{Spec}(B) \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ the continuos function defined by $f$ where if $P \in \operatorname{Spec}(B) \:$ then $φ(P)=f^{-1}(P)$. Knowing this prove:
> $$\operatorname{im}(φ)\subset V(\ker f)$$
> where $\ V(\ker f) = {\{P \in \operatorname{Spec}(A)\text{ and } \ker f \subset P \}}$

I already know that $V(\ker f)$ is homeomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec}(A/\ker f)$.

Answer (score 1):

Strong hint:

This is essentially the [correspondence theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theorem) but for rings rather than groups. Namely, ideals in $A$ that contain $\ker f$ are in correspondence with ideals in $B$, under the same action that $\phi$ has. This theorem is introduced earlier in algebra so you’ve probably already seen it.

N.B. It’s homeomor*ph*ic and mor*ph*ism.

Comment: thx man! yeah I already knew that I had seen it before but i didnt know where hehehe, sorry for the spelling, english isn't my main language.

Comment: @PabloBorrego No worries! You’re welcome

Comment: I think the correspondence theorem would require $f$ to be a surjective ring homomorphism to get a bijection; but $f$ is not being assumed surjective in the question.  For example, if $f : \mathbb{C}[x] \to \mathbb{C}[x, x^{-1}]$ is the inclusion morphism, then $\langle x \rangle$ is not in the image of $\phi$, despite the fact that $\ker(f) = \{ 0 \}$ so $V(\ker(f))$ is all of $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler But it is one direction. The same proof and same idea goes into the inclusion $\operatorname{im}\phi\subset V(\ker f)$

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution:

Let $P\in \operatorname{Spec}(B)$ lets see that $\phi(P)\in V(\ker (f)) \:$, as $P$ is an ideal we have that $0 \in P\:$ so $f^{-1}(0)\subset f^{-1}(P) \:$ that means that $\ker (f)\subset f^{-1}(P) \:$ so $f^{-1}(P)=\phi(P) \:$, we conclude that $\phi(P)\in V(\ker (f)) \:$

It's pretty simple but I think that is ok.

Comment: Thx C-RAM for the edits!

Comment: No problem. Happy to help!